# Flickr image doesn't show up on Infobox Header of CartoDB?

Tags: carto, image

I'm trying to put an image on my CartoDB infobox header from Flickr and it doesn't work. However, images from Google work.

Is there any way to make a Flickr picture work?

Comment: Hey - what are you programming in? or what software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are using the direct link to the image. If you are using the Flickr link, this is not really the link to your image but a link to the Flicker viewer that will load your image (This is, it's really a URL that gives you an HTML page, not an image).

You can play with the developer tools of your browser to get the direct URL of the Flickr image.